# Specifying config file in module returns key error

Tags: snakemake

I've been trying to run a snakemake workflow (v. 7.3.8) that has multiple modules where each has its own configuration file. There seems to be the following error when trying to specify the configuration file via `configfile: "path/to/file"`.

```
KeyError in line 5 of /dartfs-hpc/rc/home/k/f00345k/research/microbe_set_trait/workflow/rules/crc_dada2.smk:
'config'
  File "/dartfs-hpc/rc/home/k/f00345k/research/microbe_set_trait/Snakefile", line 11, in <module>
  File "/dartfs-hpc/rc/home/k/f00345k/research/microbe_set_trait/workflow/rules/crc_dada2.smk", line 5, in <module>
```

Line 5 here refers to the line `configfile: "workflow/config/dada2.yaml"`

The setup for my project is as follows:

- The module definition file is located in the subfolder `workflow/rules/`. Modules are added to the main `Snakefile` as per the tutorial. The error was obtained from running `snakemake --dry-run` from the main directory (where `Snakefile` is located).
- The config file is located in the subfolder `workflow/config/dada2.yaml`.

I'm getting this error even after stripping down the files with just placeholder code

- Yaml file (i.e. `dada2.yaml`)

```
samples:
    A: test1
    B: test2
```

- Module file (i.e. `crc_dada2.smk`)

```
from snakemake.utils import min_version
min_version("6.0")

# read config info into this namespace
configfile: "workflow/config/dada2.yaml"
print (config['samples'])

rule all: 
    output: 
        "output/test.txt"
    shell:
        "echo 'test' >> output/test.txt"
```

- `Snakefile`

```
from snakemake.utils import min_version
min_version("6.0")

module crc_dada2:
    snakefile: "workflow/rules/crc_dada2.smk"

use rule * from crc_dada2 as crc_dada2_*
```

The error message was very clear when the path to the yaml file was not well specified so I don't think it's a path issue. It might be something with the way that the yaml file was loaded but the yaml file is very simple and I copied text directly from the docs. I am a bit stumped on this issue.

**Edit**: It seems that the config file works okay if it is loaded directly in the main Snakemake file instead of through the module. I guess you can't load config files in modules!

Any assistance is very appreciated!

Comment: I have noticed, that your config filename is **dada2.yml** (as you specified) while in the module it is **dada2.yaml**. So this is a typo error? or did you miss this?

Comment: There is a `sample` in your config file and `samples` in your module. if this is not the typo, then maybe the reason for `keyError`

Comment: Thank you @c_bfx for the response! Yes I have fixed the typos and it still shows the issues. The config file was loaded in as normal when specified in the main `Snakefile` and then loaded into the module via `config['modulename']`

Comment: I think you need to specify  `dada2.yaml` in your `Snakefile` instead of `crc_dada2.smk`. this one [link](https://githubhot.com/repo/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1239) looks like a similar issue

Comment: That makes sense. I solved this per your suggestion and include one large `yaml` file in `Snakefile` and partition it accordingly to the modules by specifying `config['modulename']`

Comment: Unsure if this behaviour is expected or a bug since the documentation (https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/modularization.html) seems to suggest that you can specify config files directly in the module definitions (aka in the `smk` files)

Comment: @QuangNguyen Can you add the solution that worked for you?